# File upload failing to the server by Retrofit

Tags: android, file-upload, retrofit, okhttp

i'm trying to upload a file into server by retrofit. in postman i got api response successfully.
[image: API test in postman]

but when i call the api in my project then the api call is failing.

retrofit method:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/upload/")
fun fileUpload(@Part file:MultipartBody.Part): Call<FileUploadResponse>
```

response data class:

```
data class FileUploadResponse(
val created_at: String,
val file: String,
val id: Int,
val is_active: Boolean,
val updated_at: String,
val uuid: String  )
```

my call is:

```
 override fun fileUpload(context: Context,path: String): MutableLiveData<FileUploadResponse> {

    val apiServices = rInstance.getRetrofitInstance()?.create(ApiServices::class.java) 
    
    val file = File(path)
    val requestFile = file.asRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull())
    val filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.name, requestFile)
    Log.d("EWNMAP","path: $path, requestfile: $requestFile , filepart: $filePart")

    val call =apiServices?.fileUpload(filePart)
    call?.enqueue(object :Callback<FileUploadResponse>{
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<FileUploadResponse>,
            response: Response<FileUploadResponse>
        ) {
        if (response.isSuccessful){
            fileUploaded.postValue(response.body())
            Log.d("EWNMAP","Uploaded file: ${response.body()?.file}")
        }else Toast.makeText(context,"File Upload not successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<FileUploadResponse>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"File Upload failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    })

    return fileUploaded
}
```

i have used okhttp logger, so in logcat im getting these:

[image: logcat]

what is the problem in here ?

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for issues/problems with the Android Studio product. This question has nothing to do with the Android Studio product.